# Rendering an image in Slimdx and WPF

Tags: wpf, slimdx

Can someone explain to me how a SlimDx viewport would work in WPF?

Assuming one could render an image using SlimDX to a D3DImage and then used that D3DImage as a source for a WPF image, does that imply that the original image would first have to be rendered in SlimDX and then subsequently also be rendered in WPF? ie Are there two rendering process that must be completed?

If so does that mean that any speed advantages of using SlimDX rendering be negated because it would have to go through the WPF rendering rendering process as well?

Or am I just not understanding the process?

Comment: I haven't tryed it, but Slimdx just needs a window handle. It should also be possible to get that for a WPF window. Dx will then directly render there. Alternativelly, use a WinForms host window as your viewport.